# Ruby - Savon web services authentication

Tags: ruby, web-services, soap, savon

I'm attempting to utilize the ruby gem Savon to connect to a web service provided by propertyware (http://propertyware.com/apidocs/Getting-Started).  I've successfully connected to the service via SoapUI and executed an echoString request.  When I try to do the same via Ruby I get a null user authentication error.

Here's what I've tried in Ruby...

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'savon'

client = Savon::Client.new do
  wsdl.document = 'http://propertyware.com/pw/services/PWServices?wsdl'
  wsse.credentials 'username', 'pwd'
end

response = client.request :web, :echo_string, :body => {:arg => "Hello world."}
```

Which produces the following xml...

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:web="http://propertyware.com/pw/services/PWServices" 
    xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
    xmlns:ins0="http://propertyware.com/pw/services/PWServices" 
    xmlns:ins1="http://criteria.soap.propertyware.com" 
    xmlns:ins2="urn:PWServices" 
    xmlns:ins3="http://soap.propertyware.com" 
    xmlns:ins4="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap">
    <env:Header>
        <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
            <wsse:UsernameToken xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="UsernameToken-1">
                <wsse:Username>user</wsse:Username>
                <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">pwd</wsse:Password>
            </wsse:UsernameToken>
        </wsse:Security>
    </env:Header>
    <env:Body>
        <web:echoString>
            <arg>Hello world.</arg>
        </web:echoString>
    </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

Here's the xml produced by SoapUI...

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
    xmlns:web="http://webservices" >
   <soapenv:Header>
      <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
         <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-1" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
            <wsse:Username>user</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">pwd</wsse:Password>
            <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">R41mCRd+tY+xthhE/YISLQ==</wsse:Nonce>
            <wsu:Created>2011-10-25T09:52:40.220Z</wsu:Created>
         </wsse:UsernameToken>
      </wsse:Security>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <web:echoString soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
         <arg xsi:type="xsd:string">?</arg>
      </web:echoString>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

One obvious difference is that SoapUI includes a nonce key and a createdAt timestamp.  I'm not sure how to make savon do that without moving to digest auth. (and fwiw that doesn't work).

I'm not real savoy in the ways of web services - any guidance would be much appreciated.

Also - here's the response when I attempt to connect via savon:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <soapenv:Fault>
            <faultcode xmlns:ns1="http://xml.apache.org/axis/">ns1:Server.Unauthenticated</faultcode>
            <faultstring>User 'null' not authenticated (unknown user)</faultstring>
            <detail>
                <ns2:hostname xmlns:ns2="http://xml.apache.org/axis/">rcpppwwwapt012.realpage.com</ns2:hostname>
            </detail>
        </soapenv:Fault>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

TIA!
Bob

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the digest in the wsse to true.  This will instruct Savon to add the nonce and createdAt to the request:

```
wsse.credentials 'username', 'pwd', :digest
```

See the comments of [this object for more info](https://test.kuali.org/svn/student/deploymentlab/trunk/examples/ubc/course_migration/vendor/gems/savon-0.7.8/lib/savon/wsse.rb)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Unfortunately as I noted in the question, setting the digest to true encrypts the password and that doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

In Savon version 2  you need following:

```
client = Savon.client do
  wsdl 'https://webservice/theservice.wsdl'  
  wsse_auth("user", "pass", :digest)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the first step would be to deal with the error.

> ```
> <faultstring>User 'null' not authenticated (unknown user)</faultstring>
> ```

Your credentials aren't being passed to the service.

Comment: Yeap.  That's what this question is asking - why is that so?  The request looks like they're being sent to me - not sure why the server isn't acknowledging that.